# Is there a way how to replicate the subpixel rendering look of Windows/Outlook/browsers in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, anti-aliasing, subpixel-rendering, browser

I would like to replicate the antialiasing made by my browser in photoshop. Look at this picture: It is 500% image of standard 13px Arial #464646 font. First line is screenshot from browser(chrome), other lines are some of the antialiasing options from PS.

Notice the color change on the first line. Does it have something to do with ClearType?

Can I somehow replicate the first line in PS?

[image]

Comment: one potential problem with a uniform sub-pixel setting is that sub-pixel rendering depends on hardware capabilities. What you think looks good during design may look pretty bad with different hardware. So, beware and test your settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, **no**, there isn't a way to, using the tools that Photoshop has by default, replicate the different browsers' rendering (note that all browsers render text in a distinct way). That's one of the reasons lots of designers create mockups straight in html/css, because of these discrepancies.

There are, however, Photoshop actions and plugins you can download to allow sub-pixel font rendering:

- [Sub-pixel font rendering](http://dribbble.com/shots/258339-Sub-pixel-font-rendering-in-Photoshop) by Dmitry Tsozik
- Laurent Baumann's Photoshop Action ([video](http://cubes.fr/37dx), [download](http://cubes.fr/631e))

Comment: But why? I know ClearType is subpixel technology and PS cannot do subpixel rendering, but when you print screen it and put it into PS, it isnt subpixel any more, right? Like I did on the image...

Comment: Really have no experience with antialiasing technologies, so maybe what I have said might sound silly or weird:)

Comment: @user2330401 JohnB just mentioned sub-pixel plugins in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/graphic-design-corner), just edited the question!

Comment: @user2330401 i am wondering about this too: does it make sense to enable subpixel antialiasing when rendering the font to an image? i think no, but i couldn't find definitive source. i would think the "subpixel" effect would morph into whole pixels and make the font worse (depending on size of font?)

Comment: This is an old question but I want to point out that subpixel font rendering in an image is only going to look good when the image is viewed 1:1 on a display that has the correct subpixel layout. These days screens have a large variety of subpixel layouts, so it doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

As Yisela mentions, the sub-pixel rendering is from the OS/Browser, while PhotoShop uses it's own anti-aliasing methods.

That said, if you really want to replicate it, type out your text in the browser, style with FireBug the way you want, then screen shot, paste into PhotoShop.